# Dynamo DB, delete multiple records using Global Secondary Index(GSI) with _id (Partition key)

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Is it possible to delete multiple records from a Dynamo table using GSI _id (Partition key), rather than querying first to get the keys and deleting one by one, can someone please suggest what I should do? thanks.

Comment: Which api are you using low level, high level?

Comment: using nodejs and lambda

Comment: As far as I know there is no way to delete as you describe. You will have to make a list and then delete from that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two reasons you cannot:

1. You cannot modify GSIs directly, only the base table.
2. You cannot delete using a query constraint even on the base table, only by enumerating the primary keys of the items to delete.